# colors messed up (distorted) when making a gif from png files using ffmpeg

Tags: ffmpeg, png, gif

I have a sequence of png images: `image_00.png`, `image_01.png`, `image_02.png`, etc. I want to convert them to a gif, so I tried the command

```
ffmpeg -i image_%02d.png video.gif
```

Unfortunately, the resulting gif has distorted colors. More specifically, it added a weird sort of yellow haze around some objects in the video.

I also tried using the command above with all possible pixel format options (which I determined using the command `ffmpeg -h encoder=gif`): `rgb8`, `bgr8`, `rgb4_byte`, `bgr4_byte`, `gray`, `pal8`. For example `ffmpeg -i image_%02d.png -pix_fmt rgb8 video.gif`. Unfortunately, all of the resulting gifs had some sort of color distortion.

I also observed that this distortion does not occur if I convert the images to mp4 instead of gif. However, if I try converting that mp4 to a gif, I end up with the distortion again.

**How can I produce this gif without color distortion?**

Answer (score 22):

I was able to fix this problem by first generating a palette for all of the png images. I then used that palette to create the gif:

```
ffmpeg -i image_%02d.png -vf palettegen palette.png
ffmpeg -i image_%02d.png -i palette.png -lavfi paletteuse video.gif
```

For more info, see the "palettegen" and "paletteuse" sections of https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html

Comment: This produces "Thread message queue blocking" error messages in version git-2020-02-09-5ad1c1a , rather confusingly. Was working at one time, suspect my frames are too big now.

Comment: @ConradB Yeah I get that message sometimes too. I don't think it will affect the output though. But you can often fix it by manually setting the thread queue size with the `-thread_queue_size` option, e.g., `ffmpeg -thread_queue_size 1024 -i image_%02d.png -i palette.png -lavfi paletteuse video.gif`.